# Getting additional info using Google's Gson

Tags: java, ajax, json, gson

I have a program that I found on SO that allows the user to input a query and search using Google with whatever is inputted. The program then returns the first 4 results that Google gives. Here is the code:

```
public class TestGoogleSea {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String address = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
        String query = "who was the 19th president of america";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        URL url = new URL(address + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
        GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);

        int total = results.getResponseData().getResults().size();
        System.out.println("total: "+total);

        // Show title and URL of each results
        for(int i=0; i<=total-1; i++){
            System.out.println("Title: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(I).getTitle());
            System.out.println("URL: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(I).getUrl() + "\n");
        }
    }
}


class GoogleResults{

    private ResponseData responseData;
    public ResponseData getResponseData() { return responseData; }
    public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) { this.responseData = responseData; }
    public String toString() { return "ResponseData[" + responseData + "]"; }

    static class ResponseData {
        private List<Result> results;
        public List<Result> getResults() { return results; }
        public void setResults(List<Result> results) { this.results = results; }
        public String toString() { return "Results[" + results + "]"; }
    }

    static class Result {
        private String url;
        private String title;
        public String getUrl() { return url; }
        public String getTitle() { return title; }
        public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
        public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
        public String toString() { return "Result[url:" + url +", title:" + title + "]"; }
    }
}
```

For this specific case, (when the query is "who was the 19th president of america") the output is this:

```
Total: 4
Title: Rutherford B. Hayes - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_B._Hayes
Title: List of <b>Presidents</b> of the United States - Wikipedia, the free <b>...</b>
URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States
Title: Rutherford B. Hayes | The White House
URL: http://www.whitehouse.gov/about/presidents/rutherfordbhayes
Title: <b>American President</b>: Rutherford Birchard Hayes - Miller Center
URL: http://millercenter.org/president/hayes
```

Now, if you were actually searching "who was the 19th president of america" on Google, in addition of list of the sites, you would see the picture of Rutherford B. Hayes with his name and the option to read "more about Rutherford B. Hayes". What I'm asking is if there is anyway I can get that information, the short little description of Hayes that Google got from Wikipedia most preferably as a string, or if that's not possible due to the limits of Gson?

Comment: Stack Snippets only support JavaScript, HTML, and CSS at this time.

Comment: sorry, the only reason i did it tbh was so you could see the code the way it looks in an IDE

Comment: It's not a problem; I'm just letting you know for future reference (I'm not sure why you're even allowed to put snippets in posts not tagged with the languages they support).

Comment: I think what you meant is Google's Knowledge Graph. Google use [Freebase API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/). Specifically, I think the [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview) is what you want.

Comment: I tried that but I can't find the .jar file for import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;